# PowerBI filter Table on 2 different columns whose values are obtained from another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am new to PowerBI. I am trying to implement the following scenario in PowerBI

I have the following 2 tables -

```
Table 1:

| ExtractionId | DatasetId | UserId |
| -- | --- | --- |
| E_ID1 | D_ID1 | sta@example.com |
| E_ID2 | D_ID1 | dany@example.com |
| E_ID3 | D_ID2 | dany@example.com |


Table 2:

| DatasetId | Date | UserId | Status |
| --| --- | --- | --- |
| D_ID1 | 05/30/2021 | sta@example.com | Completed |
| D_ID1 | 05/30/2021 | dany@example.com | Completed |
| D_ID1 | 05/31/2021 | sta@example.com | Partial |
| D_ID1 | 05/31/2021 | dany@example.com | Completed |
| D_ID2 | 05/30/2021 | sta@example.com | Completed |
| D_ID2 | 05/30/2021 | dany@example.com | Completed |
| D_ID2 | 05/31/2021 | sta@example.com | Partial |
| D_ID2 | 05/31/2021 | dany@example.com | Completed |
```

I am trying to create a **PowerBI** report where, given an extraction id (in a slicer), we need to identify the corresponding **DatasetId** and **UserID** from **Table 1** and use those fields to filter **Table 2** and provide a visual of user status on the given date range.

When I am trying to implement the above scenario, I am creating a Many-Many relationship between DatasetID columns of Table1 and Table2, but cannot do the same for UserID column simultaneously as I get the following error :
**You can't create a direct active relationship between Table1 and Table2 because an active set of indirect relationship already exists**.

Because of this, given an extractionId, I can filter on DatasetID but not UserId and vice versa. Could you please help me understand what mistake I am doing here and how to resolve the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This case you said too. You can only merge two or more columns. Than you will create relationships.

[image]

[image]